# Upgrading Spring from 3.0.5 to 3.2.18 - Resources like images, CSS and JS are not accessible

Tags: spring, spring-security, upgrade, javabeans, spring-3

I am new to Spring and started working on upgrade from 3.0.5 to 3.2.18, I have tried to modify the versions and change the artifact ID's to the new version (e.g org.springframework.core to spring-core, etc..) and updated the XSD versions from 3.0 to 3.2 in the declarations. I am facing one issue with the intercept-url in the applicationcontext-security.xml

```
<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
<custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationProcessingFilter"/>
<custom-filter position="LAST" ref="loadUserContextFilter"/>
<logout logout-url="/static/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/login" />

<!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
....
...
..

<intercept-url pattern="/admin/campus/buildings/new" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_RES.APP.CAMPUS.ADMIN_DEV','ROLE_RES.APP.CAMPUS.ADMIN_FULL')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/campus/buildings/*/sitesofservice/new" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_RES.APP.CAMPUS.ADMIN_DEV','ROLE_RES.APP.CAMPUS.ADMIN_FULL')"/>
.....

<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_RES.APP.CAMPUS.ADMIN_FULL','ROLE_RES.APP.CAMPUS.ADMIN_DEV','ROLE_RES.APP.CAMPUS.ADMIN_DIFF')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/batch/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_RES.APP.CAMPUS.ADMIN_BATCH')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" filters="none" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
```

In the above file, <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" **filters="none"** access="permitAll" /> application is throwing below exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The use of "filters='none'" is no longer supported. Please define a separate  element for the pattern you want to exclude and use the attribute "security='none'".
```

I tried different approaches by removing the filters="none" and creating a new http attribute with security=none but none of them worked.

I referred to the below option
https://www.baeldung.com/security-none-filters-none-access-permitAll#security-none
and added a new http element, but still no luck.

After the above change, the file looks like below

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
   ...
   ...
```

The application is building and deploying successfully, but images, CSS and JS are not loading. Not getting any errors in the logs (I am using IntelliJ by creating a new local tomcat server for deploying and testing the application)

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please show how you are referring to css or images in html

Comment: Attached the web-app structure
In the header.jspx added the image as below
<spring:url var="logo" value="/resources/images/logo.png" /> 
  <img src="${logo}" alt="Logo" />

Comment: that is helpful, but I want to see how you wrote `<link href="../styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">` line of code in html. Also in which folder are the html files?

Comment: Below is the code in default.jspx and login.jspx (the files are present under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/
<spring:url value="/resources/styles/campus.css"
    var="campus_css_url" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
 href="${campus_css_url}" />

Answer (score 1):

what I see is that in your XML spring configuration file you wrote `<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>` but in the image you showed css and js are located under `styles` and `js` so I'd try this XML configuration:

```
<http pattern="/styles/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>
```

Otherwise you should move JS and CSS under a folder called `resources` but this would imply modify every JSP or any front-end technology you are using to call these resources; the impact would be greater but, maybe, the solution would be cleaner

Answer (score 1):

From a security point of view, the only requirement is just `permitAll` all the resources (js, images and styles) that you need.

You can do it with the following configuration:

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/styles/**" access="permitAll"/>
```

Maybe you already are doing that, but if it is not the case, you can use the resource mapping mechanism that Spring MVC provides to serve static content.

You can configure it like this in your MVC configuration:

```xml
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/styles/" />
```

Then, you only need to point at the specific resource in your pages:

```xml
<link href="<c:url value="/style/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is working fine for me. I ma using SPring-Security 3.2 version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

  
    <security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/login.jsp*" security="none"/>


    <security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/denied.jsp" servlet-api-provision="false">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/dashboard"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="true" logout-success-url="/login.jsp" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true"/>
        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsp" session-authentication-error-url="/login.jsp" session-fixation-protection="newSession" />
    </security:http>

</beans:beans>
```

To access the css on jsp or something, there are ways and one of them is like this:

First add this in JSP file:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Second is to refer it like this:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/style/campus.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, but still did not work. did you have a mapping for resources/** in the servlet mappings or created a separate config and added in the web.xml

Comment: No, I have css, js, iamge folders and added those path as is mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @SudheerDonaboina as per the image, your css files are under webapp not under resources folder. Please check ...are you missing something. If they are under webapp folder then this should work: *<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/campus.css">*

Comment: @SudheerDonaboina ... Modified my answer ... please try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/styles/campus.css" />`

Comment: Thanks for the update, it did not work for me. I am trying to access them directly and gets a 404. I have tried using static and it worked fine, not sure why resources are not working.

This is the path of the static
CamusWeb/static/styles/campus.css

Comment: I had a similar issue with spring security, I switched from an absolute path to a relative path and it worked for me. Let's try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/campus.css" />`

Comment: no luck :( when we add the ../, it is checking for the path outside the application context. 
https://localhost:8443/styles/campus.css

Comment: ok sounds like a clue, what about `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/campus.css" />` ?